# как установить компоненты галп из package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Такой вопрос у меня есть папка в ней - package.json и нужные в нем компоненты. Какой командой я могу их установить ?

```
{
  "name": "acidus",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "HTML5 Template",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "keenthemes.com",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-changed": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.10",
    "gulp-htmlhint": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-rtlcss": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: `npm install --save-dev` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В папке в которой находится **package.json** следующая команда

```
npm install
```

установит все что прописанно в package.json.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install